# What went wrong with my Bisection method algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, newtons-method

I'm working on my assignment where I must workout the bisection method on python. The algorithm looks correct in my eyes but when I run the code, I get a

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and
>   'NoneType'

.
Whats wrong and how can I fix this?

Q: Represent a polynomial p(x) = a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>x + a<sub>2</sub>x<sup>2</sup>+⋯+a<sub>n</sub>x<sup>n</sup> as a list of coefficients [a<sub>0</sub>,a<sub>1</sub>,…,a<sub>n</sub>]. Write a function called poly_critical which takes 4 input parameters p, a, b and N where p is a Python list of numbers representing a polynomial  p(x) , a and b are numbers defining an interval  [a,b] and N is a positive integer.

The function poly_critical implements  N  iterations of the bisection method applied to the equation  p′(x)=0  and returns an approximation of a critical point  c  where p′(c)=0  for  c∈[a,b] .

For example, if p = [1,-1,1,0,0,1] (which represents  p(x)=1−x+x<sup>2</sup>+x<sup>5</sup> ), a=0, b=1 and N=10 then the function returns 0.4212656546685004 which approximates a solution of  5x<sup>4</sup>+2x−1=0 .

The function poly_critical may terminate in 4 ways:

If `len(p) < 2` (p is linear), the function should print 'No critical points.' and return None.
If either initial endpoint is a critical point, return the endpoint.
If values at both endpoints and midpoint have the same sign at any iteration, the function should print 'Bisection method fails.' and return None.
The function implements N iterations of the bisection method successfully and returns the midpoint of the Nth subinterval.

My algorithm:

```
def poly_critical(p,a,b,N):

    dp = [n*p[n] for n in range(1,len(p))]

    if len(p) < 2:
        print("No critical points")
        return None

    an = a
    bn = b

    def dP(x):

        seq = [dp[i]*x**i for i in range(1,len(dp))]
        sum_seq = sum(seq)
        return sum_seq

    if dP(an)*dP(bn) >= 0:
        print("Bisection method fails.")
        return None

    if dP(an)*dP(bn) < 0:
        mn = (an+bn)/2

        for n in range(1,N+1):
            mn = (an+bn)/2

            if dP(mn)*dP(an) < 0:
                an = an
                bn = mn

            elif dP(mn)*dP(bn) < 0:
                an = mn
                bn = bn

            elif dP(mn) == 0:
                return mn

            else:
                print("Bisection method fails.")
                return None

        return (an + bn)/2
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `dP()` function return a value?

Comment: Also, you have to re-assign your `mn` within the `for`-loop, otherwise your method will always fail.

Comment: Ok, i fixed `dP()` to return `sum_seq` and added `mn = (an + bn)/2` inside the `for`-loop. Now I have an assertion error saying the return value should be a float. Whats next?

Comment: AssertionError: Return value should be a float. @ThomasKühn

Comment: You need to extract a [mcve] from your code. This is required by the site guidelines and your question is considered off-topic without it.